# NodeJS WriteFile CreateWriteStream

Tags: node.js, stream, request

Alright. Have these 2 pieces of code:

```
// first example
request(imageUrl).then((data) => {
  var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('doodle');
  wstream.write(data);
})
// second example
request(imageUrl).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle2'));
```

What I try to do is to save an image to disk. Second example works fine. But my question is: both examples do same task, but why do they produce different results?
Btw thats request-promise module in examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var request = require("request-promise");
var fs = require("fs");
var imageUrl = "http://www.biografiasyvidas.com/biografia/m/fotos/mandela_nelson_5.jpg";
request({
    "uri":imageUrl,
    "encoding": null
}).then((data) => {
    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('doodle.jpg');
    wstream.write(data);
});
```

Encoding must be null in that case.
See the README.md, search encoding
https://github.com/request/request